# Storing a time_point outside of the application

Tags: c++11, timestamp, c++-chrono

I am using an `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point` in my program. 
When the application stops I want to save to the `time_point` to a file and load it again when the application starts.

If it was an UNIX-Timestamp I could simply store the value as integer. Is there a way to similarly store a `time_point`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Choose the precision you desire the timestamp in (seconds, milliseconds, ... nanoseconds).  Then cast the `system_clock::time_point` to that precision, extract its numeric value, and print it:

```
cout << time_point_cast<seconds>(system_clock::now()).time_since_epoch().count();
```

Though not specified by the standard, the above line (de facto) portably outputs the number of non-leap seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.  That is, this is a [UNIX-Timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

I am attempting to get the above code blessed by the standard to do what it in fact does by all implementations today.  And I have the unofficial assurance of the std::chrono implementors, that they will not change their `system_clock` epochs in the meantime.

Here's a complete roundtrip example:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>


int
main()
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;

    stringstream io;
    io << time_point_cast<seconds>(system_clock::now()).time_since_epoch().count();

    int64_t i;
    system_clock::time_point tp;
    io >> i;
    if (!io.fail())
        tp = system_clock::time_point{seconds{i}};
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will check it tomorrow!